# Action in Front of 2 Nouns

Tags: grammar

頭を抱えるわたしとフランの前で、ギルがルッツに向かって吠えた。

Are both characters doing the action of 頭を抱える (わたし and フラン), or is it just わたし? I've been told that it's ambiguous / based on context. Does an action like this normally modify both nouns connected by と or is just the first.

Comment: Technically it's ambiguous, but in this case it's usually safe to assume it's `頭を抱える[わたしとフラン]`. Of course, it's unless there's a special context like Fran being petrified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of syntactic ambiguity, and is in no way limited to Japanese. There is no general rule here unfortunately - you have to infer based on context. In the same way that `頭を抱えるわたしとフラン` could be either

> [頭を抱える[わたしとフラン]]
>
> [頭を抱える[わたし]]とフラン

English sentences like `The bear rushed toward the terrified cat and dog` can be parsed as either of

> [terrified [cat and dog]]
>
> [terrified [cat]] and dog

Sometimes it's ambiguous even with context, although excluding bad writing, if it's ambiguous it often doesn't matter (I.E. either interpretation would be fine).